# Making aufs union mounts read-write

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, aufs, union-mount

So I've got two systems, `lucyvanpelt` and `schroeder`.

lucyvanpelt's `/home` is exported read-write to schroeder via NFS. Its location on schroeder is `/mnt/home/lucyvanpelt`

I want to union-mount it with schroeder's home, so I do as follows:

```
mount -t aufs -o br:/mnt/home/lucyvanpelt:/home none /home
```

It works just fine, except:

```
mount: block device none is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

And I'm not sure what to do about this. Like I said, the NFS export from lucyvanpelt is read-write (I have triple-checked this, though I don't know if it'd be relevant if it weren't).

Comment: What does the `dmesg` say after you mount it ?

Comment: aufs au_wh_init:502:mount[840]: an error(-13) on the writable branch /(nfs)

Answer (score 2):

In an aufs union-mount, a branch and the mountpoint cannot be the same. Use this:

```
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/mnt/home/lucyvanpelt=rw:/home/schroeder=ro none /path/to/mountpoint
```

Normally if you want to merge 2 directories, you have to specify what should happen if something is written on it. As you can see, you can specify each branch with `rw` (readwrite) or `ro` (readonly).

In the example above, when you write something in `/path/to/mountpoint`, that will be written on the branch `/mnt/home/lucyvanpelt`, which is readwrite. This directory is overlays the other one.